# set a constant language to CLPlacemark instance class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, localization, hebrew

i have looked every where and didn't found an answer for this one.

i'm building an iOS app that uses the location (lat + long) of the user
creating a CLPlacemark, and sends the street + country to the server and get back a respond according to this location.

now the server can get only hebrew values, and the CLPlacemark values are changes according to the operation system of the user.

can i set a const language to the CLPlacemark class instance? 
i want that the CLPlacemark will return hebrew regardless from the operation system of the user

here is my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         placemark.

         self.countryTextBox.text =[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"];
         self.citiTextBox.text =[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"City"];
         self.streetTextBox.text =[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Street"];
         self.zipCodLbl.text =[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"ZIP"];


         //NSLog(@"%@",placemark.addressDictionary);
         NSLog(@"%@",[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"]);
         NSLog(@"%@",[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"City"]);
         NSLog(@"%@",[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Street"]);
         NSLog(@"%@",[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"ZIP"]);

         [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
         [self.animationBar stopAnimating];



             }];

}
```

thanks a lot.

idan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a hard days of searching im finally solve it.

in the view did load just add this line of code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"he"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

if this will help somebody - great!

Comment: i'm glad i have help another israeli developer :)
enjoy (tavala!:))

Comment: you could also add this line in file `main.m` before `return UIApplicationMain`

Comment: This clobbers the user's system wide preferences. It would be really, really bad practice to not save their settings and restore them immediately after you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Messing with user's system preference is BAD PRACTICE!!
You should use instead:

```
NSLocale *yourLocal = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de"];
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: preferredLocale:yourLocal completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

}];
```